# Web Client Upload Values

Tags: c#, webclient, web-crawler

I want to make a desktop application that enters a value in textbox and performs button actions for example design an application that enters value in google search box at google.com  and performs action as when any one presses search button i wrote a code but it threw exception The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string uri = "http://google.com";

NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();

nvc.Add("search", "afnan");            

byte[] response = wc.UploadValues(uri, nvc);
textBox1.Text=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UploadValues` is trying to do a `POST` (by default, at least; some other verbs are allowed, but they essentially still treat it as a body payload). It *sounds* like you just want a `GET` query like http://www.google.com/search?q=afnan - so just url-encode `"afnan"`. Note, however, that you should **always** observe the target site's [Terms and Conditions](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS) - in particular section 5:

> You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers)

If you do this, expect to get black-listed.

Comment: I am lucky to get answered by a moderator thank you sir.Let me google and i will get to you after some home work

Comment: and for the website i am working they support it i mean they have plugins for joomla woerpress etc su they allow these operations

Comment: I have started a vs ASP.Net website in vs that is by default template and in that there is a login page .I modified above code to login to that page but response i am getting is simple data as it was downloaded usind webclient DownloadData